# How to set an own Exception on wrong database connection?

Tags: php, database, exception, kohana, kohana-3.2

When I'm trying to connect to wrong database I'm getting standart kohana exception message like this:

```
Database_Exception [ 1049 ]: Unknown database 'mywrongdatabase'
MODPATH\database\classes\kohana\database\mysql.php [ 108 ]
    protected function _select_db($database)
    {
        if ( ! mysql_select_db($database, $this->_connection))
        {
            // Unable to select database
[line 108]          throw new Database_Exception(':error',
                array(':error' => mysql_error($this->_connection)),
                mysql_errno($this->_connection));
        }

        Database_MySQL::$_current_databases[$this->_connection_id] = $database;
```

This came out from file

```
MODPATH\database\classes\kohana\database\mysql.php [ 108 ]
```

How to set (and where) own message instead of standart kohana's exception? Also I don't want to modify any kohana standart modules (like database) or system files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with try/catch, but I left both error_log and throw new Exception because I don't know which one you need.

```
try{
    //code with connection
} catch (Exception $e){  
    error_log("This is my own message");
    throw new Exception( 'Something really gone wrong', 0, $e);
}
```

Comment: where I cand do that? Or it is possible only inside a module file?

Comment: I found this question and answer here on SO - you can try it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831402/custom-exception-handling-in-kohana3

Comment: Okey, I found out that I can realy override kohana exception class as he did, but not the custom error, because in my example I have `Database_Exception` and thats can be a many things, like wrong db name or the user/password data. Instead of what he has in his example: strikt `HTTP_Exception_404` error handle.

Comment: Maybe to check this in the `case` block... hmm

Comment: There has to be "Database_Exception" somewhere in your code. Try to search for it and make the same thing he did for HTTP_Exception.

Comment: Thats what I'm saying, he didn't did an `HTTP_Exception`, he did `HTTP_Exception_404` and thats a different staffs, isn't?

Comment: Would be cool if it will something like this:       `case 'Database_Exception_1049':
    echo 'Wrong Database';
    return TRUE;
   break;`